# Regarding generic Where T

Tags: c#, where-clause

```
void LoadParameters<T, TValue>(TValue strategy)
        where T : Parameters
```

Saw a code like this. Will the program still work correctly without the where statement?

Comment: The code is expecting `T` to be of type `Parameters`. If the method is using any specific members of the type then it might fail if wrong type is passed.

Comment: `Parameters` are not really parameters. They are classes/interfaces/... `T` is supposed to inherit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If it compiles without the where statement, it will work correctly. However, chances are the coder did not simply put it there without reason. If you remove it, it will likely not compile and hence not work.

Comment: Thanks. Maybe the programmer put there to make sure that others inheriting from his class does not pass a wrong type?

Comment: If it would compile without the `where`, it is not the wrong type. Remove it and compile and you will get the errors where the compiler *expects* `T` to be of type `Parameters`.

Answer (score 1):

That `where` clause is called a "generic type constraint".  Usually `T` can be any type and you must write your generic code with that in mind.  By constraining `T` to be, inherit or implement a specific type, you gain the ability to refer to the members of that type in your generic code, because the compiler is assured that any object used will be that type.  You can also use `class`, `struct` or `new` as generic type constraints, which enforce `T` being a reference type, a value type or having a parameterless constructor respectively.